# background of div wont change transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a div 'floater_EditData_Panel_popup' which contains updatepanel, placeholder, and more divs.

I want to increase the transparency of the outer div 'floater_EditData_Panel_popup', to allow the user to see the background, only slightly.

So far the background colour of the div remains white,while the text boxes are faded

```
.floaterDiv{
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 450px;  
  width: 800px; 
  border: solid 1px blue; 
  /*background-color:white;*/
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  margin:1; 
  text-align:left; 
  outline-style: none;
  display:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index:999999999999;
  /* background-blend-mode: multiply;*/
}



<div id="floater_EditData_Panel_popup" title="Feature Information" class="floaterDiv"> 
    <p1>Select a feature to view/edit feature information.</p1>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanelDetails1" updatemode="Conditional" Childrenastriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
          </asp:PlaceHolder>
          <br />
          <br />
          <div id="EditDataPanelMessageOutput" style="color:Red;">

         </div>
          <div id="FeatureMeasureOutput"></div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <div class="buttonwrap">
            <div id="Span2" class="ActionBtns" style="display: inline-block;" >
              <asp:button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" value="Save" Text="Save" OnClientClick="ValidateEditData();" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="g_currentSelectedLayerName" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="valSummary1" HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:" DisplayMode="BulletList" EnableClientScript="true" ShowSummary="true" Enabled="true" />

        </ContentTemplate>

      </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

which produces the following:

[image]

please advise

Comment: First of all, avoid using `opacity` for this purpose. Better to use an `rgba()` background color instead. Second, there might be another wrapper element having a white background color around `.floaterDiv`. If any, remove its background color.

Comment: Try to change the background to black instead white `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Comment: @HashemQolami thanks for reply iv tried rgba but no effect.

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for reply changin bkground colour to black makes no diff

Comment: @John Also check if the wrapper have background color. It looks like jQuery UI, if so, it would help if you could provide an online example.

Comment: In your browser, inspect the element and look for a non transparent white div wrapping the element.

Comment: Yes I had another wrapper on the div which I was unaware about. thanks for the replies guys

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: 0.4;
```

This is affecting the contents of the DIV, not the background itself.

You should also change the RGBA values to

```
rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
```

For a white semi-transparent background

Answer (score 0):

```
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 450px;  
  width: 800px; 
  border: solid 1px blue; 
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
  /* overrule other css statements */
  margin:1; 
  text-align:left; 
  outline-style: none;
  display:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  zoom: 1;
  z-index:999999999999;
```

If this does not work, you should check if another CSS statement is changing the background to the color white or #FFF. Check chrome and inspect the element for style

Comment: sorry I forgot to remove that from the text, had removed it from code but no difference

Comment: Did you also remove all the opacity stuff?

Comment: Add !important to overrule other statements

Comment: cheers for replies. had another wrapper around the div. but good to know '!important'